# How can I convert this pdo connection to use socket | PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Essentially I need to convert the following pdo connection method to reference my mysql socket connection file - this is for my localhost environment. Connection to the localhost mysql database works fine in mysql workbench, just not sure how to reference the socket instead of the host address in PDO:

**Current:**

```
$host = 'localhost:8889';
$user = 'root';
$pass = 'root';
$db = 'mydb';

$dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=$this->charset";
$this->pdoConnect  = new \PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $this->options);
```

Need to use the following socket file:

```
/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Comment: That's the [`unix_socket`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.connection.php) option.

Comment: Using `$host = '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock';` and `$dsn = "mysql:unix_socket=$host;dbname=$db;charset=$this->charset";` as suggested gives `SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory`

Comment: A) Does that file exist? B) Can you use this option with the `mysql` command-line tool to confirm it works?

Comment: It's worth noting if you're using macOS that [Homebrew](https://brew.sh) is often a better way to run MySQL than things like MAMP which are primarily geared towards Windows users with none of the tools macOS ships with.